# How to get random rows from a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering how to get random rows within a SQL query since the full query has over 10 Billion rows and would explode our servers.

How can I query a subset which is sampled in this query structure?

```
SELECT 
a,b,c
FROM test 
WHERE    
test.a= 123
AND test.b ILIKE '10008383825311900000' 
LIMIT 1000000
```

Comment: Check this: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random  Contains a lot of efficient algorithms

Answer (score 3):

The canonical answer is to sort and use `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by rand()
limit 100;
```

**But do not do this!**  Instead, use `rand()` in a `where` clause.  For a 1% sample:

```
select t.*
from t
where rand() < 0.01;
```

Random sampling methods in MySQL tend to require scanning the entire table, which is going to be expensive in your case.

EDIT:

To optimize your query, I would start by using `=` rather than `ILIKE`:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM test 
WHERE test.a = 123 AND
     test.b = '10008383825311900000' 
LIMIT 1000000;
```

You want an index on `test(a, b, c)`.

Comment: I added my query and hope you can have a look at it and tell me how to restructure. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer.

```
select * from (
    select 
        a,b,c
        ,row_number() over (order by a) as rn
    from test 
    where     
        t1.a= 123
        AND t1.b ILIKE '10008383825311900000' 
        ) t1
     inner join 
         (select floor(rand()*100) as rn from test limit 1000000) t2 on t2.rn = t1.rn
```

Comment: I just updated and added my query. Could you take a look please and tell me how to incorporate your code?